# error "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py"

Tags: python, lib, libs

i am using kali linux 2020.4 iso

i am using this repository -----> https://github.com/SkyBulk/bin2sc

Would you help me solve this error?

I have the libraries installed, I don't know what error could be

```
#python3.10 bin2sc.py shellcode.asm sc_app linux x64

/usr/bin/ld: shellcode.o: en la función `_start':
shellcode.asm:(.text+0x1): referencia a `print' sin definir
objdump: 'shellcode': No hay tal fichero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lobo/bin2sc/bin2sc.py", line 100, in <module>
    opcode = sc_bin('shellcode', 'intel')
  File "/home/lobo/bin2sc/bin2sc.py", line 22, in sc_bin
    lines = subprocess.check_output(['objdump', '-d', '-M', syntax, obj])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 425, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 529, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['objdump', '-d', '-M', 'intel', 'shellcode']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: Provide more info on the situation.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with the `subprocess` module itself; It looks like  something is calling the `objdump` command, and that command is returning an error code. Look at the error message printed by `objdump`: `objdump: 'shellcode': No hay tal fichero` ("No such file"). That's the source of the error.